# Display RFID tag data on an LCD display

Tags: rfid

I am complete electronics newbie, so please bear with me :)

I would like to connect an LCD directly to a 433 MHz RFID tag. So whenever I swipe the RFID tag near the RFID writer, the values that are written to the RFID tag would be displayed on the LCD.

Is this possible, if so, can someone please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** To clarify, the RFID tag needs to be on the same PCB as the display.

**EDIT - 14/05/2012:** Looks like there are a lot of questions on what I am trying to do, so here is what I am trying to achieve:

- I want to create a pocket device (more or less the size of an iPhone) that is able to receive a numeric password from a server within the office
- The device needs to have a battery life of 3-6 months at least
- The range that the device should be able to get the password should be up to 50 meters
- The numeric password on the device will be updated every 1-2 minutes

Since battery life is a constraint, and updates are only every 1-2 minutes, I thought medium range RFIDs would be the best option.  Let me know if you can think of a better solution.

Comment: This entirely depends on the RFID reader and the LCD and you haven't provided any information about what you want to use. In general case, you'll need to have some sort of microcontroller that will read the data from the reader, process it and send it to the LCD. If you're lucky, you might be able to find a reader that can directly drive an LCD, but I doubt it.

Comment: For the LCD, something like this http://www.sparkfun.com/products/710 .  Is it possible to avoid using an RFID reader, and connect the microcontroller directly to the RFID?

Comment: Directly to RFID what? You'll definitely want some sort of reader. There are microcontrollers with integrated RFID readers, like for example [ATA5505](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATA5505.aspx), but it's only available in QFN38, so unless you have a PCB, you'll need to find an adapter too. I think sparkfun may have some, but I'm not sure. You'll also need to check if the operating frequency matches the one your cards use.

Comment: From what I can see, microcontrollers which can read RFID seem to be a bit rare to find.

Comment: thanks for the help so far!  Let me clarify, I am planning to use a medium range RFID, probably a 433Mhz.  I want the RFID tag to be on the same PCB as the reader, and the LED display.  Since RFID tags are activated when in ranage of a reader, how do I deal with that since it will be on the same PCB?

Comment: Why would you want the tag to be on the PCB? It suggests you just want a fixed ID. Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve as it sounds like we are trying to answer an odd question. I have built LF RFID readers from just Atmel processors, but you need an RF front end for HF. 433MHz however is not what I would call RFID - these are active tags ie. just small transceivers, unlike LF and HF tags that are passive.

Comment: Unique ID in RFID tags is readable and not writable (as you have suggested). Most RFID card tags have this ID printed on the back, so you could just read it without need for a microcontroller and LCD. If you insist, then you could print this fixed value on LCD with a microcontroller, but I don't see any use for that. I suggest you to do some research about RFID in general, since you seam to miss a lot. In case you want to make your own tag: http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag. You can add LCD to it if you really insist, but that would not be a task for a newbie.

Comment: @avra - There are writable RFIDs too!

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions being made. 433MHz tags aren't that common or standardised.

Comment: @cybergibbons I've updated my original question to reply to your comments.  I hope it makes more sense now on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @rob - it sounds like RFID isn't want you want at all. You want a low power RF transceiver.

Comment: @cybergibbons thanks, I will look into a low power RF transceiver then.  I will accept Stevevh's answer for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is it possible to avoid using an RFID reader, and connect the microcontroller directly to the RFID?"

Using the RFID tag directly with a microcontroller without an RFID reader is useless, and often impossible.
Commercial RFID tags usually have only 1 connection to the outer world, and that's wireless. They draw their power supply from an RF carrier and send their data over that same carrier by loading it, so that the reader will see dips in the signal.
If you want to skip the RF, and directly connect, you may as well use a serial EEPROM which you read an ID from.

> "the RFID tag needs to be on the same PCB as the display."

An RFID reader is the RF interface, which will pass the code received from the tag as an electrical signal to the microcontroller. So the microcontroller with its display is connected to the *reader* side, not the *tag*'s.

For a *reader* this only makes sense. The display will change for each different tag the reader detects. If you connect the display to the tag it will always show the same code. That's unless you want to *write* to the tag to change its code.

The solution then would be to make your own tag. You'll need a microcontroller with a coil antenna connected that picks up the carrier, and which you will modulate. The other side of the microcontroller will drive the display. This will need much more power than can be drawn from the carrier, so you'll need at least a battery power supply. In which case an LCD is preferred over a LED display, because it uses less power.

[Beth](http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/) made her own RFID tag with just a small microcontroller and a coil. You'll need a bigger microcontroller with enough I/O to control the display.

**Which microcontroller?**
An LCD module with integrated driver is easiest to use, though [the one you chose](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/710) is way overkill for just displaying numbers (unless you want to add fancy graphics too). It's a graphical display which AFAICS doesn't have a character generator, so you'll have to draw your digits on it yourself.
Anyway, whether you use a character display or a graphical one, the interface will be more or less the same: 8 (or 4) data lines and a few control lines. Any microcontroller with minimum **16 I/Os** will do. Remember you'll also need at least one, maybe two I/O pins for talking to the RFID reader/writer.
Like most of these modules this one needs a 5V power supply. So choose a **5V** microcontroller. If your favorite controller only works at 3.3V you can use level shifters to interface the two, but it's better to avoid them if not really needed.
You'll want a microcontroller with some **EEPROM** to store the code. Again, if yours doesn't have that you can use an external one, but you should be able to find a controller with the EEPROM on-chip.
In the Atmel ATMega series the [ATMega8](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2486.pdf) is a controller that fits the bill.

---

See also [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19089/are-there-types-of-passive-rfid-tag-which-can-connect-to-control-logic).

Comment: Exactly, the RFID tag will be written to, so the code will change.  I want to be able to display that code on the LCD.  Any suggestions for the microcontroller?

Comment: @rob - What does the data you want to display look like? Numeric, hexadecimal, text, 8 chars, 20 chars? This will have its impact on the controller choice. Tell me more and I'll add a section to my answer.

Comment: Numeric (eg: 1,123 ), and I want to display the numbers onto an LCD like this one - http://www.sparkfun.com/products/710 .